# Why do some list methods in Python work only with defined variables?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a.append(4)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3].append(4)
>>>
```

Why do [`list`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) methods in Python (such as `insert` and `append`) only work with defined variables?

Comment: Did you mean to append the string `'4'` rather than the number `4`?

Comment: It doesn't metter in this case :)

Comment: >>> [1, 2, 3].count(2) # proves that list methods also works with not only the defined variable.

Comment: Sure, just checking it wasn't going to cause you a problem somewhere else. :)

Comment: @wrongite you're right. Edited my question

Comment: @Aran-Fey how can this be duplicate of newer question?

Comment: @DaniilRyzhkov Age doesn't matter; what matters is which question has the better answers and is a better dupe target.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the second sample nothing is printed, because `append`, that was called on a list (**note that append was actually performed**), returns `None`.

Alternatively you should mention that `a.append(4)` also gave you a blank line (as your first sample shows), and final output of a first code sample was a representation of result of `a` expression, not `a.append('4')` expression.

Nothing is printed after `append` call in both cases because it is a representation of `None`.

Comment: @Daniil -- Why does `list.append` return `None`?  Because Guido said that's what it should return ...

Comment: @Daniil: The Python shell only displays results of the last operation if it's not `None`, which is why you didn't even see that. Try `print [1, 2, 3].append(4)` and you'll see the result of the `append()` method.

Comment: @Daniil: Also try `[1, 2, 3] + [4]` to see that you _can_ append to a literal.

Answer (score 4):

`list.append` returns `None`.  `a.append('4')` didn't print anything either since things which return `None` don't print anything in the interactive interpreter ...

Note that your second method call *did work*.  It appended `'4'` to the list, you'll just never get to see it since you immediately lose any handle you had on the list you created.

Answer (score 4):

It does work. It just doesn't print anything, the same way that `a.append(4)` doesn't print anything. It's only because you saved the list as a variable that you can display its new value.

Comment: **+1** - Didn't know about `_`

Comment: It's pretty handy when you're using the Python shell and you forget to assign your previous calculation to a variable. `a = _`

Comment: Also, this doesn't actually work - `_` is being populated from a previous operation in your shell

Answer (score 1):

Another way to concatenate lists:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] + [4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Note that in this case, a new list is created and returned. `list.append` adds an item to an existing list and does not return anything.

Comment: What if I want to use `insert()` method?

Comment: This is fundamentally different than `[1,2,3].append('4')` though.  Adding lists creates a **new** list, rather than adding to an **existing** list.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that the list methods works only with defined variables. It's that the specified method ***append*** of list always return None while change the internal state of the list in question.

Answer (score 0):

The function only works with defined variables because that is how it is indented to work. From the [python documentatio](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html)n:

> list.append(x)
>
> Add an item to the end of the list; equivalent to `a[len(a):] = [x]`.

Note that is does "work" in the sense that a value is returned and the function does not raise an exception. But the results are lost because you have no reference to the modified list.

---

As an aside, some languages enforce naming conventions to make it explicit that a function modifies a given object. For example, Ruby and Scheme append a `!` - so in this case the function might be called `append!`. Such a naming convention helps make the intent of the function more clear.