# Why does append() always return None in Python?

Tags: python, list, append, nonetype

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
print(list.append(4))   ## WRONG, print does not work, append() returns None

## RIGHT:
list.append(4)
print(list)  ## [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I'm learning Python and I'm not sure if this problem is specific to the language and how `append` is implemented in Python.

Comment: in the first instance, your printing the result of the append operation. if append() was completed successfully, it's returning 'None', as in, problems encountered: None

Comment: `append` will return `None` if it worked. There is not much more to it than that.

Comment: Ah it would be easier to understand (at least for me) if the comment in the original code had mentioned that `append` is a `void` function. This makes sense, thanks.

Comment: The convention that *most* of the standard library uses is that if a method is supposed to mutate the object *in place*, then it should return `None`.  There are a few exceptions where following this rule would make the code harder to use (`list.pop` is one example).  But those are definitely exceptions and not the rule.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12217203/748858) is *very similar* to the one you asked.  Check out the answers there as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682567/why-does-pythons-list-append-evaluate-to-false

Comment: `append` is an in place operation

Answer (score 100, accepted):

`append` is a mutating (destructive) operation (it modifies the list in place instead of of returning a new list). The idiomatic way to do the non-destructive equivalent of `append` would be

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> l + [4]
[1,2,3,4]
>>> l
[1,2,3]
```

to answer your question, my guess is that if `append` returned the newly modified list, users might think that it was non-destructive, ie they might write code like

```
m = l.append("a")
n = l.append("b")
```

and expect `n` to be `[1,2,3,"b"]`

Answer (score 29):

It is a convention in Python that methods that mutate sequences return `None`.

Consider:

```
>>> a_list = [3, 2, 1]
>>> print a_list.sort()
None
>>> a_list
[1, 2, 3]

>>> a_dict = {}
>>> print a_dict.__setitem__('a', 1)
None
>>> a_dict
{'a': 1}

>>> a_set = set()
>>> print a_set.add(1)
None
>>> a_set
set([1])
```

Starting in Python 3.3, this is now more [explicitly documented](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#built-in-types):

> Some collection classes are mutable. The methods that add, subtract,
>   or rearrange their members in place, and don’t return a specific item,
>   never return the collection instance itself but `None`.

The Design and History FAQ [gives the reasoning](http://docs.python.org/faq/design.html#why-doesn-t-list-sort-return-the-sorted-list) behind this design decision (with respect to lists):

> **Why doesn’t `list.sort(`) return the sorted list?**
>
> In situations where performance matters, making a copy of the list
>   just to sort it would be wasteful. Therefore, `list.sort()` sorts the
>   list in place. In order to remind you of that fact, it does not return
>   the sorted list. This way, you won’t be fooled into accidentally
>   overwriting a list when you need a sorted copy but also need to keep
>   the unsorted version around.
>
> In Python 2.4 a new built-in function – `sorted()` – has been added.
>   This function creates a new list from a provided iterable, sorts it
>   and returns it.

Answer (score 4):

One word of advice would be to avoid using key words or functions as variable names.  In your code above, you use list as a variable:

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
```

I would advise against using `list` as a variable name as [list](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#list) is actually already defined as a builtin type.  As ChaseTheSun and squiguy pointed out, there isn't much more to it then

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
lst.append(4)
print(lst)  ## [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Lower-case L as a variable name is bad too, just because it looks too much like the number 1.  I like to use `lst`.

Answer (score 4):

`list.append()` is an in-place operation, meaning that it modifies the state of the `list`, instead of returning a new `list` object.

All functions in Python return `None` unless they explicitly return something else. The method `a.append()` modifies `a` itself, which means that there's nothing to return.

Another way you can see this behavior is in the difference between `sorted(some_list)` and `some_list.sort()`.

If you don't want to append `"x"` to `a`, then you'll need to use the second snippet, or you can simply concatenate:

```py
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = a[1:] + ["x"]
>>> b
[2, 3, 4, 'x']
```

To further clarify:

```py
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = a[1:].append("x")
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a[1:]
[2, 3, 4]
>>> type(b)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Notice that `b` is `None`, since the `list.append()` method returns `None`. Notice also that `a` wasn't actually modified. This is because you were appending to a slice of `a`, but not actually saving that slice anywhere. Notice what happens if you do `a.append("x")`:

```py
>>> b = a.append("x")
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'x']
>>> type(b)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

`b` is still `None`, but now `a` got modified.

Answer (score -1):

It does not return anything. it appends/add to the variable, to see you should use the first variable which used to append in print

```
friends=["Rajendra V"]
friends.append("John")
print(friends)
```