# None value appended in the list output

Tags: python, nonetype

```
def foo(i, x=[]):
    x.append(x.append(i))
    return x
for i in range(3):
    y = foo(i)
    print(y)
print(y)
```

this results in

```
[0, None]
[0, None, 1, None]
[0, None, 1, None, 2, None]
[0, None, 1, None, 2, None]
```

Why is the `None` being appended in the list? I checked some threads on this topic, unfortunately I couldn't still understand why `None` is being printed.

If I replace `x.append(x.append(i))` with just `x.append(i)` the `None` goes away. That made sense, but I'm still unclear why the `x.append(x.append(i))` adds a `None`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does append return none in this code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-return-none-in-this-code)

Comment: What is the expected behavior of `x.append(x.append(i))`?

Answer (score 1):

Alecxe is correct. To summarize, append(value) does not have a return value, and will thus return None. If you wish to append with a return value in a semi-pythonic manor, use: `y = x = x + [value]` this will set y equal to x with value appended in both.

However, in addition to that, part of the problem is that you are using a default argument that is mutable.
This means that every time you call the function with the default value of x, the list, x will be the same it was when the last call finished.
Consider the following

```
def add(num, x=[]):
    x.append(num)
    print x
```

Calling `add(4)` will print `[4]`, then calling `add(5)` after will print `[4, 5]`

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot. i ran the code . i see that print x will give a list as you described. thanks

Comment: Great answer! didn't realise a default could mutate like that. Could you please make this answer complete by also summarising @alecxe's answer too? I realised otherwise this is better as a comment (but I realise you don't have comment anywhere yet).

Answer (score 0):

That's because the [`.append()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method appends to a list and returns `None`:

```
>>> x = []
>>> print(x.append(1))
None
```

In other words, the inner `x.append(i)` would append `i` and the outer would append `None`.