# Loop gets stuck on 1st iteration

Tags: python, list, if-statement, for-loop, web-crawler

While trying to create a web crawler, I'm trying to define this function:

```
#a and b are lists.
def union(a, b):
    i = 0
    while i <= len(b):
        if b[i] in a :
            a = a.append(b[i])   
        i = i + 1    
    return a
```

then testing it, I input:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,4,6,9]
union(a,b)
```

It keeps giving me the error

```
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I've seen a solution for this problem in another thread by editing my condition to `if a and b[i] not in a:`, but while testing, that only solves it until I append 1 element of b to a, then stops working.

Comment: Please properly format your code next time. It's one click on "edit" , and one click on format as code.

Comment: Use [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set), not lists. Sets have an inbuilt `union` you can take advantage of. No need to roll your own.

Comment: this is **not** how python `while` loop works. Please read a basic Python tutorial.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-return-none-in-this-code

Comment: that's completely different code now, and it doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is changing code fundamentally, trying to skip past the necessity to read a basic python tutorial: at this level, it's impossible to answer.

Comment: `append` returns `None` so `a = a.append(b[i])` effectively overwrites the value of `a` with `None`. Just do `a.append(b[i])`

Comment: @MarcusMüller give them a break! This is a new user who is having trouble coding and the original code makes perfect sense, it just isn't a case one would use `while` loops in python.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I'm all yours on being nice to new users, but the point here is that we should teach new users how to help *themselves*, and in this case, not "hotfixing" something just quick, but trying to understand what one's doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

See the updated and commented code below

```
#a and b are lists.
def union(a, b):
    i = 0
    while i <= len(b):
        if b[i] in a :
            # the problem lies here. append returns None
            # a = a.append(b[i])
            # this should work
            a.append(b[i])   
        i = i + 1    
    return a
```