# Python: How to add tuple to an empty list?

Tags: python-2.7

I've looked around at other posts on here for a solution to my problem but none of them seems to work for me. I want to append a tuple to (what starts out as) an empty list. I've checked my code and it looks like whenever I try to just append my tuple it turns the list into a NoneType object. Here's what I've got:

```
list_of_pairs = []
for player in standings:
    opponent = standings[standings.index(player) + 1]
    matchup = (player[0:2] + opponent[0:2])
    list_of_pairs = list_of_pairs.append(matchup)
    print "ADDED TO LIST: " + str(list_of_pairs)
```

Each `player` in the standings list contains a tuple with four elements. I've tried using index and re-assigning `list_of_pairs = [list_of_pairs, matchup]`, but nothing seems to be returning the right thing (i.e. `[(player),(next player), (another player), (etc.)]`. Every time I print "added to list" I just get `ADDED TO LIST: None`. I've checked `matchup` as well and it's definitely storing the first two values of the respective players fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does append return none in this code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-return-none-in-this-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because appending an element to a list returns `None`, which you are then printing when you do:

```
list_of_pairs = list_of_pairs.append(matchup)
print "ADDED TO LIST: " + str(list_of_pairs)
```

For example:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = a.append('hello')
>>> print a
['hello']
>>> print b
None
```

Comment: yes, it's means you can translate "list_of_pairs = list_of_pairs.append(matchup)" to "list_of_pairs.append(matchup)". then try again.

Comment: So could I get round this by generating a new variable (let's say `appended_list`), and doing  `appended_list = list_of_pairs.append(matchup)` instead? Would that then mean that `list_of_pairs` would actually contain the values needed while `appended_list` would return None?

Comment: Forget the above! I think I just realised what you mean! The problem is that I'm re-assigning the variable to itself when I'm appending it right? So the solution is just `list_of_pairs.append(matchup)` without `list_of_pairs = `

Comment: Thanks for this, I literally spent half a day staring at this trying to figure it out!