# How to join multiple rows into single line using python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am running below code it's running.

```
for row in rows:
    print("%s:"%row[0])
```

Result:

```
Jan
Feb
Mar
Apr
```

Excepted result: `'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'`

i am trying to insert data into list based on below code but i am getting an error.

```
lst = []
print(lst)
    for row in rows:
        print("%s"%row[0])
        lst =lst.append("%s"%row[0])
        print(lst)
```

i am run above code getting below result:

```
[]
Jan
None
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

How can i solve this?

Comment: 1. Don't use `list` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `list` type. 2. The code in your 1st code block will _not_ produce the result you've shown. What happened to the `:` ? 3. The `list.append` method mutates the list object in-place and returns `None`.

Comment: i renamed the variable name also it's doesn't work to me.

Comment: i modified my question also. please check that

Comment: Now that you've read "Why does append return none in this code?" do you understand how to fix your code? To make the `print` function in your loop print everything on one line pass it an arg of `end=' '`. See the docs for further details.

Comment: "This question was marked as an *exact* duplicate of an existing question." I believe this is incorrect. If the `AttributeError` is solved, the question itself is still not solved and is way different than the one marked as duplicate @TigerhawkT3 @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: It might be that the question should still be closed, but right now it's marked as a duplicate to a question which it is not a duplicate of. Solving the error provided in this post via the means provided in the duplicate post does not actually answer the question that was originally asked; "How to join multiple rows into single line using python?"

Comment: I update my question what i am getting. still getting None value. It's append the value into  list. How can i do this?

Comment: @VenkateshPanabaka See the question marked as duplicate, it should be enough to fix the `AttributeError`

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Please remove this question as duplicate. Please read the question before mark as duplicate. If your solve this problem it would be great.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen No, done lot of research before raising a question. Problem still not solved. i updated my question please check that

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Please remove this question as duplicate. Please read the question before mark as duplicate. If your solve this problem it would be great.

Comment: The `AttributeError` is directly explained in the other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-return-none-in-this-code)