# arithmetic progression in python 3.6 in def function

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I write python code in atom editor and make program arithmetic sequence in function

this is the code:

```
def arithmetic(n):
flag = n

for flag in range(10):
    number = []
    result =  number.append(flag**2)
    return result
```

the result when print(arithmetic(5)):

```
None
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does append return none in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-return-none-in-this-code)

Comment: `append/extend` always return `NoneType`

Comment: The code is not indented properly. Please edit your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code.

```
def arithmetic(n):
    flag = n
    number = []
    for flag in range(10):
        number.append(flag**2)
    return number

print (arithmetic(4))
```

Comment: In Python 3.x this will raise an error. You need parenthesis when calling `print`

Comment: Thank you @Eskapp I just tested only in 2.7 version

Comment: You're so helpful @skr

Comment: Glad I could help @MuhammadAkbar