# Python: How to get multiple values from user?

Tags: python

I am making a word chain game in python but I am stuck at one place.
The thing I wanted to do is

```
The game begins by asking how many people wish to play, and then prompting you to enter a name
for each of the players.
```

For this, I have created a code

```
def inputWord():
    Players = str(input("Enter Number of Players:"))
    Name = []
    WordChain = 0
    ls = list()
    PlayerNames = {}
    for i in range(0, int(Players)):
        Name = input("Enter Player Name:")
        PlayerNames = ls.append(Name)
        print(PlayerNames)
    print(PlayerNames)  

inputWord()

the Output that I am getting is 
Enter Number of Players:2
Enter Player Name:David
None
Enter Player Name:Martin
None
None
```

Instead, I need this

```
Enter Number of Players:2
Enter Player Name:David
David
Enter Player Name:Martin
Martin
[David, Martin] #list of the names for later use
```

I am new to python please help me.

Comment: `print(name)` then `print(ls)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does append return none in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-return-none-in-this-code)

Comment: Thank You Julien. That Solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append` is a python list method that is used to append new value to a existing list. The method does not return anything. When you are using:

```
PlayerNames = ls.append(Name)
```

The `Name` that you got from the user gets append to your list but it returns nothing. But you are trying to assign the returning value to `PlayerNames` variable and in that case the variable will be empty. So, whenever you are trying to print `PlayerNames`, it is showing `None`. Instead you already have user's name in your `Name` variable and you can use `print(Name)` to print the user's name on the screen.

**Your Loop Should Be Like:**

```
for i in range(0, int(Players)):
    Name = input("Enter Player Name:")
    ls.append(Name)      <-- append user's name to your list.
    print(Name)          <-- show what user has entered.
print(ls)                <-- print the whole list after the loop.
```

You should read more about python Data Structure. It has a good documentation.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Thank you SK. Fazlee Rabby.