# Why this list comprehension doesn't work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am trying to create a new embeded list from two lists(a and b) as below:

```py
list_a = ['abc','def','opq']
list_b = [1,2]
resulting_list = 
[['abc',1,2],
 ['def',1,2],
 ['opq',1,2]]
```

I have tried below below function with list comprehension, but it doesn't return expected result.

```py
def combine_list(list_a, list_b):
    return [[post].extend(list_b) for post in list_a]
```

I expected to return:

```py
[['abc',1,2],
 ['def',1,2],
 ['opq',1,2]]
```

instead, I got

```py
[None, None, None]
```

Why doesn't the list comprehension work?

Comment: The parameter is named `list_a` but the function uses `post_list`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`extend` is a mutator. It modifies the list on the left and returns nothing. List comprehensions should stick to functional, side-effect-free operations.

```
[[post] + list_b for post in list_b]
```

And change `post_list` to `list_b`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python is another example of this issue, for OP to read

Answer (score 0):

First, it shouldn't be post_list.

```
>>> [[post]+list_b for post in list_a]
[['abc', 1, 2], ['def', 1, 2], ['opq', 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def combine_list(list_a, list_b):
return [[post].extend(list_b) for post in post_list]
```

Because post_list doesn't exist anywhere in your function, or as a global variable.

Comment: This is true, but not why OP gets the behavior he is describing.

Comment: So my answer gets downvoted, because a miscalled / misplaced variable is less of an issue, than the return type of extend? Stackoverflow is just wonderful.

Comment: how can you know that post_list isnt defined in the OP code. If it wasnt deifned he would get `NameError` but he doesnt mention that just says he gets list of `None`

Comment: If the OP does not provide the correct variable, how can we assume that the output provide is correct?

Comment: Cause if it wasnt a defined variable he would get a `NameError` but thats not his compaint