# For loop changes original list variable

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

Quick question from someone with limited Python experience. So I have some lists inside a list. I want to iterate through it, append something to each iteration, and then store that in a different list.

For example:

```
var=[[1],[2],[3]]
var2 = []

for item in var:
    var2.append(item.append("x"))
```

However, rather than the expected output for `var2` of `[[1, 'x'], [2, 'x'], [3, 'x']]` I get `[None, None, None]`

I was planning to reuse my original variable, `var`, for a different purpose. However, `var` is now equal to `[[1, 'x'], [2, 'x'], [3, 'x']]`

What is going on here?

Comment: [`item.append()` modifies `item` and returns `None`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python)

Comment: I think you want to do `var2.append([item[0], "x"])
`

Comment: Try `item + ["x"]` instead

Comment: `var2.append(item + ['x'])`

Comment: Use item + ['x']

Comment: @MosheRabaev: Or to handle potentially longer `item` `list`s, `item + ['x']` or `[*item, 'x']` (the latter Py3 only) would both work.

Comment: Assign your item to a temprary variable then update it
`for item in var:
...   tmp = item
...   tmp.append('x')
...   var2.append(tmp)`

Comment: I have a meta question, trying to figure out when to comment vs answer. How come none of you posted an answer? I always feel like I'm doing something wrong because it seems like everyone just answers questions in the comments instead of posting answers

Comment: @swaggyp I didn't answer because I was pretty sure I could find a dupe for this question...but there's actually two things going on here so it's a little more nuanced. Probably worth an answer...

Comment: @Alex see also: [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) and (tangentially related, but useful) [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `append` function modifies its input. So when you call `item.append(...)`, you are modifying `item`, which is a reference to one of the elements in `var`.

You can minimally reproduce this via

```
var=[[1],[2],[3]]

for item in var:
    item.append("x")
```

In addition, the return value of `append` is `None`, so you're effectively calling `var2.append(None)` for each item, explaining your `var2` result.

To avoid this, use a non-destructive method that returns the value you want, such as

```
var=[[1],[2],[3]]
var2 = []

for item in var:
    var2.append(item + ["x"])
```

Or, better still,

```
var=[[1],[2],[3]]
var2 = [item + ["x"] for item in var]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you refer to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) `list.append` as well as others return `None` and that's what you're appending. Therefore you need to concatenate or extend the list while returning the value. I suggest using `item + ['x']` so your loop would look as follows:

```
for item in var:
    var2.append(item + ['x'])
```

Although why not just use a list comprehension for this?

```
var=[[1],[2],[3]]
var2 = [item + ['x'] for item in var]
```

Results:

```
[[1, 'x'], [2, 'x'], [3, 'x']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is the culprit. This is not that hard but we have to make sure what is going on in the nested list appends.

My solution to this would be:

```
var=[[1],[2],[3]]
var2 = []

for i in range(len(var)):
  list = []
  list.append(var[i][0])
  list.append('x')
  var2.append(list)

print(var)
print(var2)
>>> [[1], [2], [3]]
>>> [[1, 'x'], [2, 'x'], [3, 'x']]
```

Even though it may be intuitive to write:

```
for list in var:
  list.append('x')
  var2.append(newList)
```

This will change the values in the lists in the original `var` list as well.

Comment: don't use `list` as a variable name.