# Using operator = in list

Tags: python, list

I would like to understand why when I'm using the a=(with append)
the result is none.
why the var list is none.

```
a = ['a','b','b']
b = 'y'
a = a.append(b)
print (a) ---result none
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does append() always return None in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python)

Comment: How can someone be asking *why* something occurs when it is clear from the question that she doesn't realize *that* it occurs?

Comment: just delete `a = `.

Comment: the question is why it happens in python.

Comment: _the question is why it happens in python._ I'm not sure that really addresses the comment by @ScottHunter though.

Answer (score 0):

`append` returns `None`.

If you *didn't* do the assignment, `a` would have the `'y'` appended to it.