# Creating a Data frame by appending a dictionary inside a list, outcome of an external function

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, web-scraping

I'm currently working in a web scraper **my min goal is to collect data and put that data into a DataFrame**. I am having some issues trying to append some data.

**This is the code:**

```
import re  
import time
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import \
    presence_of_element_located
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

import functions_database as fd
import page_objects as po  # Internal code
import scrapers as scr  # Internal code


df_read_amz = pd.read_csv(
'/home/daniel/amazon-project-scrapers/amz_scraper.edited.csv')  
amazon_data = list(df_read_amz.ASIN)    

offers = []
for asin in amazon_data:
    amz_offers = scr.get_offers(asin)
    print('this is amz_offers', amz_offers)
    dic_amz_offers = offers.append(amz_offers)
    print('this is list dictionary', dic_amz_offers)
    df_amz_offers = pd.DataFrame(dic_amz_offers)
    print(df_amz_offers)
```

**Notice that:**

scr.get_offers(asin) is an internal function developed by a third party, it's outcome is the following:

`this is amz_offers [{'seller_name': 'Under Moments', 'seller_url': 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/aag/main/ref=olp_merch_name_1/137-8432761-0781850?ie=UTF8&asin=B00I2ZFMO4&isAmazonFulfilled=0&seller=A2EDR7YR1BSPTD', 'condition': 'New', 'delivery': 'FBM', 'shipping': 0.0, 'price': 9.78, 'number_of_ratings': 179481, 'asin': 'B00I2ZFMO4', 'parent_asin': None}]`

I am trying to make a dataframe with that outcome, the most solid idea I have is to append it to a list:

```
    ´dic_amz_offers = offers.append(amz_offers)
    print('this is list dictionary:', dic_amz_offers)´
```

**But this happens:**
´this is list dictionary: None´

```
    df_amz_offers = pd.DataFrame(dic_amz_offers)
    print(df_amz_offers)
```

**as a consequence, I also get an empty DF**

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []`

**How do I get the DataFrame I need? Thank you :)**

Comment: _But this happens: ´this is list dictionary: None´_ https://stackoverflow.com/q/16641119/11301900.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does append() always return None in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

df_amz_offers=pd.Dataframe(amz_offers) should work...

Or

```
df_amz_offers=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(amz_offers)
```

Else As there is only one dictionnary in the list do:

```
for dictionary in dic_amz_offers:
    df_amz_offers=pd.Dataframe(dictionary)

print(df_amz_offers)
```