# Can't get a for loop to work as list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

This for loop works fine but not as a list comprehension. 
The comprehension creates empty elements for each iteration.
Can someone explain what is wrong and how to fix it?

```
def GetAsciiList():
    num_list = []
    for num in range(32, 42, 1):
        num_list.append((str(num), chr(num)+" "))
    return num_list

def GetAsciiListLC():
    num_list = []
    num_list = [(num_list.append((str(num), chr(num)+" "))) for num in range(32, 42, 1)]
    return num_list

print GetAsciiList()
print GetAsciiListLC()
```

---

console output:

```
[('32', '  '), ('33', '! '), ('34', '" '), ('35', '# '), ('36', '$ '), ('37', '% '), ('38', '& '), ('39', "' "), ('40', '( '), ('41', ') ')]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to format your Python code?  Python is whitespace-sensitive and it's hard to know how to correctly edit this question.

Comment: List comprehensions resolve to a list. So you probably just want `return [(str(num), chr(num)+" ") for num in range(32, 42, 1)]`. If you append in the list comprehension, the result of the appending, `None` will be the value for each item in the list, as you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this line in `GetAsciiListLC()`:

```
num_list = [(num_list.append((str(num), chr(num)+" "))) for num in range(32, 42, 1)]
```

`num_list.append((str(num), chr(num)+" ")))` mutates the list and *returns `None`*.

I think what you want is this:

```
def GetAsciiListLC():
    """ Return list of 2-tuples containing numbers and ASCII equivalents, both as strings. """
    return [(str(num), chr(num) + " ") for num in range(32, 42)]
```

See this question for the rationale of returning None from the list.append() method:
[Why does append() always return None in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python)