# Cannot append to my list without getting a nonetype object error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
str1 = []
x = sentence.lower()
x = x.strip('.')
x = x.strip('!')
lsent = x.split()
for e in lsent:
    if e != 'the' and e != 'is' and e != 'if' and e != 'it':
        str1 = str1.append(e)
str1 = " ".join(str1)
print(str1)
```

Heres my code. When I try to append an item to the end of the list it tells me str1 is a nonetype object even though I made it a list in the first row.

Any help is appreciated I'm thoroughly confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does append() always return None in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

Python `List.append()` method returns the value of `None`. What you are trying to do, can be done simply by changing

```py
str1 = str1.append(e)
```

to

```py
str1.append(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `append` method to a `List` modifies it in place and returns a `None`. Change it for

> str1.append(e)

And just to be fair with other users, this was answered at least a couple of times. ;-)
For instance, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16641831/2705572

P.S.: In any case, it is always good to answer :-) Welcome to our Community!