# Appending to list produces None

Tags: python

Code:

```
for a in range(1,n+1):
    name = input("Enter name of passenger ")
    age = int(input("Enter age of passenger"))
    sex = input("Enter sex of passenger")
    lis= [name,age,sex]
    passengers = passengers.append(lis)

print("All passengers are :")
print(passengers)
```

I have tried this to make a ticket making software, but the names of passengers are not getting added to passengers list. The result shown is None.

Comment: just change `passengers = passengers.append(lis)` with  `passengers.append(lis)`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You already appear to have your answer but for future reference "My code is not running properly" is not a helpful title for a question.

Comment: I'll also add that `for a in range(1, n+1)` is superfluous, because a isn't used in the code. `for _ in range(n)` is cleaner.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the result of `append()` to the `passengers` variable but `append()` returns `None`. Simply remove the assignment:

```
for a in range(1,n+1):
    name = input("Enter name of passenger ")
    age = int(input("Enter age of passenger"))
    sex = input("Enter sex of passenger")
    lis= [name,age,sex]
    passengers.append(lis)
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `.append()` is `None`. Which is what you're assigning to your variable.

What you'd want instead is to define your `passengers` prior to your loop then append to it as follows

```
passengers = []
for a in range(1,n+1):
    name = input("Enter name of passenger ")
    age = int(input("Enter age of passenger"))
    sex = input("Enter sex of passenger")
    lis=[name,age,sex]
    passengers.append(lis)

print("All passengers are :")
print(passengers)
```