# Insert Element at the begining of the list

Tags: python

In following code I am trying to append string 'timeout' as first element of list `imput_cmd`. To do this, I am using `insert` at 0th index of the list. but My print statement is always returning `None`. Can someone please point what I am missing here ?

```
import subprocess

def run_command(command,timeout):
    input_cmd = command.split()
    print(command)
    print(input_cmd)
    imput_cmd_with_with_timeout = input_cmd.insert(0,'timeout')
    print(imput_cmd_with_with_timeout)



run_command('sleep 60', 10)
```

I  am using python 3.6

Comment: @dawg The function's not supposed to return anything - really it's irrelevant. The problem is actually that `imput_cmd_with_with_timeout` is `None`. See narendra's answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does append() always return None in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python)

Comment: Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists): "You might have noticed that methods like `insert`, `remove` or `sort` that only modify the list have no return value printed – they return the default `None`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list.insert` adds to the same list. It doesn't return a new list.

To insert into a new list, you need to copy contents into a new list, and then call `insert`.

```
imput_cmd_with_with_timeout =  input_cmd[:]
imput_cmd_with_with_timeout.insert(0,'timeout') 
print(imput_cmd_with_with_timeout)
# ['timeout', 'sleep', '60']
```

Comment: @dawg yes, agreed (+1)! But question is more focused on why `print(imput_cmd_with_with_timeout)` is outputting `None`.

Comment: @dawg I am returning from the real function  ,  this  is a scaled down version of actual  problem. I  am  using `imput_cmd_with_with_timeout` further in  the same function. but due t o  some  reasons imput_cmd_with_with_timeout  was None.

Comment: FWIW, the clearer way to copy a list is `input_cmd.copy()`, but I think this would actually be clearest as `imput_cmd_with_with_timeout = ['timeout'] + input_cmd`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python