# list comprehension produces None values

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

I'm trying to store the vowels and constants indices of a string in two lists, so far I have the following:

```
def my_function(string):
    vowels_index = [] # vowels indices list
    const_index = [i if string[i] not in "AEIOU" else vowels_index.append(i) for i in range(len(string))] # constants indices list
```

Some None values are present in const_index:

```
>>> string = "BANANA"
>>> const_index = [i if string[i] not in "AEIOU" else vowels_index.append(i) for i in range(len(string))]
>>> const_index
[0, None, 2, None, 4, None]
>>>
```

Is there a better way to find the two lists?

Comment: Don't do that. `append` returns nothing, so you see a `None`. You have to have a new comprehension for vowels or other ways.

Comment: use a simple for loop insteadd of list comprehension, thanks me later, but as @Austin points out, you are adding the None returned when else

Comment: Also: [Why does append() always return None in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can first use `enumerate` in a list comprehension to filter out the indices where a vowel occurs. Then you can use a `set` difference with all indices to find the complement which is where a consonant must occur.

```
def my_function(string):
    vowels = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(string) if val.lower() in 'aeiou']
    consts = list(set(range(len(string))) - set(vowels))
    return vowels, consts

>>> my_function('BANANA')
([1, 3, 5], [0, 2, 4])
```

Can unpack to get separate lists

```
>>> vowels, consts = my_function('BANANA')
>>> vowels
[1, 3, 5]
>>> consts
[0, 2, 4]
```