# How can I create and add to a list that is inside a tuple, inside a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

This is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
for (k,v), (k2,v2) in zip(name_to_phone.items(), name_to_address.items()):
        if  v2 or k2 not in address_to_all:
            address_to_all[v2] = ([].append(k),v)
```

But the list doesn't show up in the tuple when I print it, it only says none. How can I fix this?
Edit:
These are the dictionaries:

```
name_to_phone = {'alice': 5678982231, 'bob': '111-234-5678', 'christine': 5556412237, 'daniel': '959-201-3198', 'edward': 5678982231}
name_to_address = {'alice': '11 hillview ave', 'bob': '25 arbor way', 'christine': '11 hillview ave', 'daniel': '180 ways court', 'edward': '11 hillview ave'}
```

Comment: Can you add little prototype of the dictionaries?

Comment: @yagizcandegirmenci what do you mean by prototype? Id be happy to add any extra info needed.

Comment: little parts from the data like, `name_to_phone = {'key":"value", "another_key":"another_value"}`

Comment: @yagizcandegirmenci just added it! bascially, I want the names to be in that list

Comment: Please add the output that you want.

Comment: To get a list with one item, use `[k]`, not `[].append(k)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does append() always return None in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python)

Comment: @yagizcandegirmenci this is the output I want: {'11 hillview ave': (['alice', 'christine', 'edward'], 5678982231), '25 arbor way': (['bob'], '111-234-5678'), '180 ways court': (['daniel'], '959-201-3198')}

Comment: @mkrieger1 not really, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this dictionary comprehension.

```
for (k,v), (k2,v2) in zip(name_to_phone.items(), name_to_address.items()):
   address_to_all.update({v2:([key for key,value in name_to_address.items() if value == v2],v)})


Out: {'11 hillview ave': (['alice', 'christine', 'edward'], 5678982231), '25 arbor way': (['bob'], '111-234-5678'), '180 ways court': (['daniel'], '959-201-3198')}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain why this worked and my expression didn't. To me it is basically supposed to be doing the same thing.

Comment: `append` function mutates the list and returns `None`  so when you say something like `address_to_all[v2]  = ([].append(k), v)` you are actually assigning `address_to_all[v2]` with `None` so the next time when you refer that list its actually pointing the `None` not the list that's why  something like `[].append(k),v` wont work