# Conversion of result in list type

Tags: python

I actually used this below code to print the first letter of this sentence:

---

```py
st = 'Create a list of the first letters of every word in this string'

for letter in x:
    
    print(letter[0])
```

---

My output was :

```
C
a
l
o
t
f
l
o
e
w
i
t
s
```

But I want to convert my result into list and used this code:

---

```py
a = []
    
for letter in x:
    print(a.append(letter[0]))
```

---

### But my output was:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

---

How to get my result as :

```
['C','a','l','o','t','f','l','o','e','w','i','t','s']
```

Comment: Try print out ```a```.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does append() always return None in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python)

Comment: Your first code prints ***every*** letter. Not just the first of each word...

Comment: Because [`list.append()` always returns None in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python). So execute the `list.append()` command, then do the print in a separate statement.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use split.

```
a = []
for word in st.split():
    a.append(word[0])
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
a = [x[0] for x in st.split()]
```

Use **split**, please check the [official document](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

`str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)`

The default **sep=None**, which means that as long as it is a space (including tabs), it will be divided