# Square root list in python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to minimize as much as possible my coding and trying to solve problems in different ways and i wrote this code which gets a list of numbers and it returns the square root of each one number in list

```
def square_roots(l):
    squareRoots = []
    result = [squareRoots.append(math.sqrt(i)) for i in l]
    return result

l=[1,2,3]
print(square_roots(l))
```

The only problem is that it returns `[None, None, None]` instead of the square root of each number in the array.
What's wrong with it?

Comment: remove first line of your function then do `result = [math.sqrt(i) for i in l]`

Comment: You are creating a list of the return value of an append method.  The return value of append is None.  The append method *did* add the results to the squareRoots list.  If anything your return statement should `return squareRoots`.  But embedding the loop in a list comprehension is unconventional at best.

Comment: @Asocia for that matter, how about simply: `return [math.sqrt(i) for i in l]`

Comment: what are the return type and value of `list.append`, would you say?

Comment: @RufusVS Yes, even better one is `print(*map(math.sqrt, l))` but I wanted to change as small code as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.append()` (i.e. `squareRoots.append()`) returns `None`. Remove that part.

```
def square_roots(l):
    result = [math.sqrt(i) for i in l]
    return result
```

You might want to read [Why does append() always return None in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16641119/4518341)