# DIctionary does up update internal list of strings as expected; returns None instead

Tags: python, list

I have this small function that is not doing what I want it to do, and I am not sure why. The function is supposed to add the `new_text` string to the `text` list in the `wordclouds` dictionary.

```
def update(wordclouds, source, new_text):
    if source in wordclouds:
        old_text = wordclouds[source]['text']
        frank = old_text.append(new_text)
        wordclouds[source]['text'] = frank
    else:
        wordclouds[source] = {"text": [new_text]}
    return wordclouds
```

However, when I run the function, I get `None` for the `text` list as shown below.

```
>>> w = {}
>>> w = update(w, 'fred', 'I am happy')
>>> w
{'fred': {'text': ['I am happy']}}
>>> w = update(w, 'fred', 'I am not happy')
>>> w
{'fred': {'text': None}}
>>>
```

The first pass through the function gives the expected result: `{'fred': {'text': ['I am happy']}}`. But the second call to the function for some reason returns `None` for the `text` field in the dictionary. I expected `{'fred': {'text': ['I am happy', 'I am not happy']}}`

If I change the code to be this:

```
def update(wordclouds, source, new_text):
    if source in wordclouds:
        #old_text = wordclouds[source]['text']
        #frank = old_text.append(new_text)
        wordclouds[source]['text'].append(new_text)
    else:
        wordclouds[source] = {"text": [new_text]}
    return wordclouds
```

It works as expected:

```
>>> w = {}
>>> w = update(w, 'fred', 'I am happy')
>>> w
{'fred': {'text': ['I am happy']}}
>>> w = update(w, 'fred', 'I am not happy')
>>> w
{'fred': {'text': ['I am happy', 'I am not happy']}}
>>>
```

I must be missing something very basic about dictionaries and fucntions, but I just don't see it. Why is the `text` list set to `None` in the second call to the first example of the `update` function, and not the second?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is here: `frank = old_text.append(new_text)`. Think about what `append` returns, and consequently what is being stored into `frank`, and then into the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.append()` returns `None`, therefore `frank` is `None`. For more info, see [Why does append() always return None in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16641119/4518341)

Your second implementation of `update()` is correct, but in the same respect as `list.append()`, since it's mutating `wordclouds`, it shouldn't *return* `wordclouds`. And for what it's worth, you could simplify it using [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
def update(wordclouds, source, new_text):
    d = wordclouds.setdefault(source, {})
    d.setdefault("text", []).append(new_text)
```

```
>>> w = {}
>>> update(w, 'fred', 'I am happy')
>>> w
{'fred': {'text': ['I am happy']}}
>>> update(w, 'fred', 'I am not happy')
>>> w
{'fred': {'text': ['I am happy', 'I am not happy']}}
```

Comment: Ahhh, yes. Forgot that aspect of append.  Didn't know about `setdefault` for dictionaries. Thanks!