# Standard loop works when list comprehension does not

Tags: python, list, output, list-comprehension

Why the below code in where I am using list comprehension doesn't work, but the common way does it?

```
exams = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,5,1]
repeatedExams = []

# EXCPECTED OUPUT
# repeatedExams = [1,2,3]

# IF I USE repeatedExams.append(i)
repeatedExams = [repeatedExams.append(i) for i in exams if (exams.count(i)>1) and (i not in repeatedExams)]
    # OUTPUT 
    # repeatedExams = [None,None,None]

# IF I ONLY USE i
repeatedExams = [i for i in exams if (exams.count(i)>1) and (i not in repeatedExams)]
    # OUTPUT
    # repeatedExams = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,5,1]

# WORK 
for i in exams:
    if exams.count(i) > 1 and i not in repeatedExams:
        repeatedExams.append(i)

    # OUTPUT
    # repeatedExams = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: List comprehensions `append` to a new list for you; that's their entire purpose. `append` doesn't return anything, so your first way doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does append() always return None in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python)

Comment: `list(set([x for x in exams if exams.count(x)>1]))`

Comment: Thanks @usuario12339314 for my need it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

`list.append()` returns None

Comprehension returns a collection for you; you do not need to pre-define one

As you are building one, you shouldn't be using it, so `not in repeatedExams` within the comprehension isn't going to do what you want

---

If you want to count repeats, use a Counter

```
from collections import Counter

exams = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,5,1]
c = Counter(exams)
repeatedExams = [k for k,v in c.items() if v > 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to go with list comprehension, then you need to split the loop into two steps:

```py
# Keep only repetated elements
repeatedExams = [i for i in exams if exams.count(i)>1] 
# Remove duplicates of repeated elements       
repeatedExams = set(repeatedExams)
```

Comment: Use a `set` to avoid the second list comprehension.

Comment: @user12339314 That'll remove duplicates, not count them

Comment: This answer has quadratic runtime, btw

Comment: I know :) I'm just plugging everything into list comprehensions.

Comment: `... for i in repeatedExams if i not in repeatedExams` Isn't that just an expensive no-op?

Answer (score 0):

The list comprehension syntax tells Python to take an iterable, and for each element of that iterable, evaluate an expression, and then build a list out of all the results returned by that expression. `append` is what's known as an "in place" operator. What that means is that it operates not by returning a result, but by modifying the associated object. The actual value of inplace operators is generally `None`. For instance, `repeatedExams.append(i)` modifies the object `repeatedExams`. The modified version of `repeatedExams` is now stored where ther original `repeatedExams` was, and `repeatedExams.append(i)` returns `None`. Your syntax then stores all those `None`s in a list.

It may be informative to do

```
for i in exams:
    if (exams.count(i)>1) and (i not in repeatedExams):
        print(repeatedExams.append(i))
```

and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
repeatedExams = [i for i in exams if exams.count(i)>1] 
repeatedExams = set(repeatedExams)
```

Or-

```
repeatedExams = set([i for i in exams if exams.count(i)>1])
```

Comment: Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

```
repeatedExams = {exam for exam in exams if exams.count(exam)>1}
```

similar to user16198685's answer, but the `[]` brackets and 'set()' are redundant

`exam for exam in exams if exams.count(exam)>1` is a generator
`set comprehension` takes generators as arguments, as well as listcomps. So `set([])` brackets can be replaced with '{}'