# Python dictionary and arrays , howto get the arrays into the dictionary?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

What I am trying to do is build a dictionary from a database that contains 5 keys. I can't for some reason get this structure to work, as it looks like it rebuilds the array each time.
NOTE, The Input is coming from a database of bytes. leveldb
Here is the starting code

```py
 for X in world:
            if b'\xff' not in X:
                if b'\x00' not in X:
                    if b'map_' in X:
                        mapd = self.world.level_wrapper._level_manager._db.get(X)
                        data = amulet_nbt.load(mapd, little_endian=True)
                        if data.get("name") != None:
```

this is what I wish would work

```py
currentMaps[str(data.get("name"))] = {
                               "name": str(data.get("name")),
                               "map": [].append(str(X)),
                               "cols": str(data.get("col")),
                               "rows": str(data.get("row"))
                           }
```

```
OutPut: {'cmap_1': {'name': 'cmap_1', 'map': None, 'cols': '15', 'rows': '10'}, 'cmap_151': {'name': 'cmap_151', 'map': None, 'cols': '3', 'rows': '3'}}
```

this is what I'm stuck doing to get all the data

```py
currentMaps[str(X)] =  {
                                "name":str(data.get("name")),
                                "map": str(X),
                                "cols": str(data.get("col")),
                                "rows": str(data.get("row"))
                            }
```

```
OutPut {"b'map_0'": {'name': 'cmap_1', 'map': "b'map_0'", 'cols': '15', 'rows': '10'}, "b'map_1'": {'name': 'cmap_1', 'map': "b'map_1'", 'cols': '15', 'rows': '10'}, "b'map_10'": {'name': 'cmap_1', 'map': "b'map_10'", 'cols': '15', 'rows': '10'}, ........ETC
Desired Output: {'cmap_1': {'name': 'cmap_1', 'map': [map_1, etc], 'cols': '15', 'rows': '10'}, 'cmap_151': {'name': 'cmap_151', [map_157, etc]: None, 'cols': '3', 'rows': '3'}}
```

how would I build this to my desired result? With the name being the main key and having all the maps with the name in an array. if I build an array all the maps get added to the array and are not separated by name, array.clear does not work because the database is not in order.
I have tried to run it through an if statement clearing the array when the name changes. Maybe sorting first....
Any ideas.. ?

Something Like this , but this will not work

```py
dic = {}
for x in currentMaps:
dic[currentMaps[x]["name"]]["maps"] = currentMaps[x]["map"]
```

This works to reorder, How do I define this dynamically ?

```py
        dic = {"cmap_1":{
            "maps":[],
        },
        "cmap_2":{
            "maps":[],
        }}
        for x in currentMaps:
            dic[currentMaps[x]["name"]]["maps"].append(currentMaps[x]["map"])
```

```
{'cmap_1': {'maps': ["b'map_0'", "b'map_1'", "b'map_10'", "b'map_100'", "b'map_101'", "b'map_102'", "b'map_103'", "b'map_104'", "b'map_105'", "b'map_106'", "b'map_107'", "b'map_108'", "b'map_109'", "b'map_11'", "b'map_110'", "b'map_111'", "b'map_112'", "b'map_113'", "b'map_114'", "b'map_115'", "b'map_116'", "b'map_117'", "b'map_118'", "b'map_119'", "b'map_12'", "b'map_120'", "b'map_121'", "b'map_122'", "b'map_123'", "b'map_124'", "b'map_125'", "b'map_126'", "b'map_127'", "b'map_128'", "b'map_129'", "b'map_13'", "b'map_130'", "b'map_131'", "b'map_132'", "b'map_133'", "b'map_134'", "b'map_135'", "b'map_136'", "b'map_137'", "b'map_138'", "b'map_139'", "b'map_14'", "b'map_140'", "b'map_141'", "b'map_142'", "b'map_143'", "b'map_144'", "b'map_145'", "b'map_146'", "b'map_147'", "b'map_148'", "b'map_15'", "b'map_16'", "b'map_17'", "b'map_18'", "b'map_19'", "b'map_2'", "b'map_20'", "b'map_21'", "b'map_22'", "b'map_23'", "b'map_24'", "b'map_25'", "b'map_26'", "b'map_27'", "b'map_28'", "b'map_29'", "b'map_3'", "b'map_30'", "b'map_31'", "b'map_32'", "b'map_33'", "b'map_34'", "b'map_35'", "b'map_36'", "b'map_37'", "b'map_38'", "b'map_39'", "b'map_4'", "b'map_40'", "b'map_41'", "b'map_42'", "b'map_43'", "b'map_44'", "b'map_45'", "b'map_46'", "b'map_47'", "b'map_48'", "b'map_49'", "b'map_5'", "b'map_50'", "b'map_51'", "b'map_52'", "b'map_53'", "b'map_54'", "b'map_55'", "b'map_56'", "b'map_57'", "b'map_58'", "b'map_59'", "b'map_6'", "b'map_60'", "b'map_61'", "b'map_62'", "b'map_63'", "b'map_64'", "b'map_65'", "b'map_66'", "b'map_67'", "b'map_68'", "b'map_69'", "b'map_7'", "b'map_70'", "b'map_71'", "b'map_72'", "b'map_73'", "b'map_74'", "b'map_75'", "b'map_76'", "b'map_77'", "b'map_78'", "b'map_79'", "b'map_8'", "b'map_80'", "b'map_81'", "b'map_82'", "b'map_83'", "b'map_84'", "b'map_85'", "b'map_86'", "b'map_87'", "b'map_88'", "b'map_89'", "b'map_9'", "b'map_90'", "b'map_91'", "b'map_92'", "b'map_93'", "b'map_94'", "b'map_95'", "b'map_96'", "b'map_97'", "b'map_98'", "b'map_99'"]}, 'cmap_2': {'maps': ["b'map_149'", "b'map_150'", "b'map_151'", "b'map_152'", "b'map_153'", "b'map_154'", "b'map_155'", "b'map_156'", "b'map_157'"]}}
```

Comment: Needs clarification, show some example input and what you want output

Comment: Why do you have all of those `str` calls in there?  If those things are strings, they don't need to be converted.

Comment: its coming from a byte database. leveldb

Comment: I can't understand the question. How **exactly** is the input formatted? "a database of bytes" tells me approximately nothing. What do you mean when you say that the database "contains five keys"? What is the actual code you are using - not just the line you use to create the dict, but enough code to see the overall process and explain what `data` etc. look like? What actually is *wrong with* the actual output vs. desired? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, and make it possible for other people to see the problem for themselves.

Comment: Basically: we need to have code that creates a value for `data`  that is *identical* to what you get in your actual code, ideally without requiring a third-party library or a database file. You should make sure you know how to inspect values in Python and make sure that you can reproduce them exactly. Based on the output sample, you should also make sure you understand what a `bytes` object is and how it works.

Comment: I can't even begin to guess what you want `[].append(str(X))` to do. In particular, what is `X`? But you should also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python .

Comment: for x in currentMaps:
            dic[currentMaps[x]["name"]]["maps"] = [currentMaps[x]["map"]}

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand exactly what your data looks like, but assuming it's something like this

```
data = [{'name': 'cmap_1', 'map': ['map_1', 'map_2'], 'cols': '15', 'rows': '10'},
{'name': 'cmap_151', 'map': ['map_157', 'map_158'], 'cols': '3', 'rows': '3'}
```

You should be able to get it into a dictionary formatted as you'd like with a simple comprehension like

```
print({x['name']:x for x in data})
```

Output:

```
{'cmap_1': {'name': 'cmap_1', 'map': ['map_1', 'map_2'], 'cols': '15', 'rows': '10'}, 'cmap_151': {'name': 'cmap_151', 'map': ['map_157', 'map_158'], 'cols': '3', 'rows': '3'}}
```

Comment: The Data is coming from the map_x keys, they each contain the name, col, and row data. very hard to make a working example without the database.

Comment: I added the start code

Answer (score 0):

So for my situation, where it is hard to determine what the names will be, I figured out that this works, It's most likely not the best way but it will work.
Can't find and set the names in the loop without resetting the array. So I am forced to do this.

```py
dic = {}
        for x in currentMaps:
            dic[currentMaps[x]["name"]] = {}
            dic[currentMaps[x]["name"]]["maps"] = []
            dic[currentMaps[x]["name"]]["col"] = int
            dic[currentMaps[x]["name"]]["row"] = int
        for x in currentMaps:
            dic[currentMaps[x]["name"]]["col"] = currentMaps[x]["cols"]
            dic[currentMaps[x]["name"]]["row"] = currentMaps[x]["rows"]
            dic[currentMaps[x]["name"]]["maps"].append(currentMaps[x]["map"])
```

This works :)
Is there a better way?