# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'print' error

Tags: python

So for a task I need to be able to reflect the y-value of a tuple.
This is what I have so far, but I keep getting this error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'print'

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def print(self):
        print((self.x, self.y))
    def reflect_x(self):
        if self.y < 0:
            print((self.x, abs(self.y)))
        if self.y > 0:
            print((self.x, -abs(self.y)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = Point(1,4)
    p1.reflect_x().print()

    p2 = Point(-3,5)
    p2.reflect_x().print()

    p3 = Point(-3,-5)
    p3.reflect_x().print()
```

These are the values I should be getting:

```
(1, -4)
(-3, -5)
(-3, 5)
```

The bottom part (in `if __name__ == "__main__":`) is a test code which I'm not allowed to change, so the main problems should be lying in the top part, so basically inside the Point-class.

Comment: I've taken a wild guess based on the look of the code that this is Python, and edited the tags so that someone who knows Python can find the question and help you. If that's wrong, please click [edit] and choose a more appropriate tag. If I'm right, you might also want to confirm the version of Python you're using.

Comment: `reflect_x()` is a method which is not returning anything. It has no `.print()` method associated with it because when you call `reflect_x()` it returns `None`. Also, your `reflect_x()` method *already* prints information, why are you separately trying to call `print()`? The only way this would work the way you intend would be to create a new instance of your Point class and return it from `reflect_x()`.

Comment: Maybe this is beside the point, but why are you using `-abs()`? For that matter, why not skip the `if`s and `abs()` entirely and just do `-self.y`? Maybe you ultimately want `self.y *= -1`

Answer (score 1):

The method `reflect_x` implicitly returns `None`. You have to either call the custom print method on the class object itself or return `self` in your `reflect_x`.

**EDIT** by *call the custom print method on the class object itself* I mean to change the last part of the code as follows

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = Point(1,4)
    p1.reflect_x()
    p1.print()

    p2 = Point(-3,5)
    p2.reflect_x()
    p2.print()

    p3 = Point(-3,-5)
    p3.reflect_x()
    p3.print()
```

which will work because the custom print method is a member of the Point class.

And the second option of returning `self` from the `reflect_x` method will work as well because we return the reference of the object instance. See this: https://www.online-python.com/hHg4Ya3yG7

These two points only focus on the aspect to resolve the `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'print'` issue. To achieve the results we are looking for, modify the code like so:

```py
def reflect_x(self):
    if self.y < 0:
        self.y = abs(self.y)
    elif self.y > 0:
        self.y = -abs(self.y)
    return self
```

which will print the desired result of

```py
(1, -4)
(-3, -5)
(-3, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method `Point.reflect_x()` doesn't have a return, so it returns `None`.
You are trying to call the function `print` in `Point.reflect_x()`, wich is the source of your error.

To solve this, just call `Point.print()` instead of `Point.reflect_x().print()`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = Point(1,4)
    p1.reflect_x()
    p1.print()

    p2 = Point(-3,5)
    p2.reflect_x()
    p2.print()

    p3 = Point(-3,-5)
    p3.reflect_x()
    p3.print()
```

Also, change your reflect_x method:

```
def reflect_x(self):
    self.y *= -1
```

Comment: OP updated the question and this answer no longer works :(

Answer (score 1):

Your reflect function doesn't change the class - it returns None, which doesn't have a print function, as the error says

To "reflect over the X-axis", you don't need absolute values, just multiply by negative one

Plus, adding a print method to the class is not Pythonistic. You should implement `__str__`

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return f'({self.x},{self.y})'

    def reflect_x(self):
        self.y *= -1
```

Then you can do

```
p1 = Point(1,4)
print(p1)
p1.reflect_x()
print(p1)
```

If you need the exact code shown in the main execution part and can only change the class, then

change only

```
def reflect_x(self):
    self.y *= -1
    return self
```

Then this will work

```
p1 = Point(1,4)
p1.reflect_x().print()
```

Comment: +1, I'm out of votes for today. This is really the only answer that attempts to fix the *real* issues with OP's code.

Comment: First of all thank you. Unfortunately, the bottom part is a test code which I'm not allowed to change, so there must be something else that I should be changing on the Point-class, but I genuinely have no clue what it is.

Comment: @sari023 I've updated my answer with those changes

Comment: @One FYI I posted [my own answer](/a/69651438/4518341) taking the opposite strategy (new instance instead of `self`).

Answer (score 1):

`reflect_x()` should return a `Point` object.

```
def reflect_x(self):
    cls = type(self)
    return cls(self.x, -self.y)
```

It'd also be possible to modify `self` then return it, but [conventionally, mutators return `None` in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16641119/4518341) to avoid confusion.

By the way, this style facilitates [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining), and it's commonly used in Pandas for example.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.print()` after `p1.reflect_x`:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        
    def print(self):
        print(self.x, self.y)
        
    def reflect_x(self):
        if self.y < 0:
            print((self.x, abs(self.y)))
        if self.y > 0:
            print((self.x, -abs(self.y)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = Point(1,4)
    p1.reflect_x()

    p2 = Point(-3,5)
    p2.reflect_x()

    p3 = Point(-3,-5)
    p3.reflect_x()
```

Comment: This will print that function output. Seems OP wants to print the instance after calling that function (as well)

Comment: I think that wasn't their intention. Anyway, with this edit the output gets printed as shown in the question.