# Making a definition that doesn't modify the input of a list when switched?

Tags: python

I’m trying to shift the first and second characters without the input being modified, but because I’m using `holder` to hold the input seems to be modified, does anyone know another way of doing this which wouldn’t modify it?

```
shiftlist = ['a', 'b', 'c']


def switch(shiftlist):
    holder = shiftlist[0]
    shiftlist[0] = shiftlist[1]
    shiftlist[1] = holder
    return shiftlist
```

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a copy of the list instead of the list itself.

```
print(switch(shiftlist.copy()))
print(shiftlist)
```

```
['b', 'a', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, read [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. Why is this and how can I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it)

Now, this case is a bit different because it's a function. Passing an argument does an *implicit* assignment to the parameter name in the function scope.

One option is to pass in a copy (like in [Stuart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69716841/4518341)), but that means the input list would get modified *and* returned, which is [unconventional](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16641119/4518341). Instead, make a copy *inside* the function.

```
def switch(shiftlist):
    new = shiftlist.copy()
    new[0], new[1] = new[1], new[0]  # BTW, no temporary variable needed
    return new

L = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(switch(L))  # -> ['b', 'a', 'c']
print(L)  # -> ['a', 'b', 'c']
```