# Appending list but got "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'" Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I keep having this error on my code, which says:
"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'"

But there is interesting fact, it only occurs when "n" is odd.
Here is the piece of code I'm using:
Note: I'm using Python 2.7.18

```
def sol(n, df):    
    if n == 1:
        result = df
    elif n == 2 or n == 0:
        df.append(1)
        result = df
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        df.append(n/2)
        df = sol(n/2, df)
    else:
        df_2 = df[:]
        df_2 = df_2.append(n-1)
        n_2 = n-1
        df_2 = sol(n_2, df_2)
        
    return df

df = []
n = input('n == ')
sol(n, df)
```

The error is as follow:

```
n == 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Challenge_3_1_vTest.py", line 27, in <module>
    solution(n)
  File "Challenge_3_1_vTest.py", line 6, in solution
    print((sol(n, df)))
  File "Challenge_3_1_vTest.py", line 21, in sol
    df_2 = sol(n_2, df_2)
  File "Challenge_3_1_vTest.py", line 12, in sol
    df.append(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen? Did you add a `print()` statement at the start of `sol()` to print the values of the arguments it receives?

Comment: I've just realized that for some reason the "df" variable is passing as an "<type 'int'>" and not as an array

Comment: @wovano Thanks for the welcoming! I've searched for the answer here on SO and other plataforms, the closest answer I got wasn't sufficient for my problem!
I expected the code to return an array containg all the numbers it has passed thru. 
Trying to debug it now, I've realized that for some reason when passing to the function the variable "df" is recognised as "<type 'int'>", that's why I might be getting this error, but the strange fact is, it's also "<type 'int'>" when I do it with number that are power of 2 and the code works!

Comment: @Igor According to the error `df` is `None`, not `int`.

Comment: @DeepSpace My problem needs to be solver in Python 2! I'd rather use Python 3 as well!
And forgive me for my ignorance, isn't the "n=3" and reproducible example?

Comment: It wasn't before you edited the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does append() always return None in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python)

Comment: @DeepSpace @wovano forgive me for my mistake, I've printed `df` inside the `sol(n,df)` and it's receinving the variable as a list!

Comment: We all make mistakes, no problem. But IMHO the question is not useful for others since it's just a bug in your specific code. There could be thousands of reasons to receive the `'NoneType' object has no attribute...` error, and the general solution is debugging. Your solution is only applicable to your specific code and probably not for anyone else. So you could also choose to delete the question, but I guess that's up to you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

The append function doesn't return a thing, that's why I was having the error and was passing a none when using number that are not power of 2.

`df_2 = df_2.append(n-1)`

This line of code was the source of the problem, I should have done:

`df_2.append(n-1)`