# Updating Value in a list of dicts appears to not work

Tags: python

some_key in dictionaty data is a list.
some_key contains a list of dictionaries.
I would like to update the value of one of the keys in this list for each item.

Below is my solution to update the dicts.

```
data["some_key"] = [some_dict.update({"other_key": some_dict["other_key"].upper()}) for some_dict in data["some_key"]]
```

But this appears to output:

```
{'total': 1, 'some_key': [None]}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `update` works in place, it doesn't output anything (i.e. None)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict.update()` is an in-place operation, so it [returns `None` to avoid confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16641119/4518341). That means you don't need to modify the list at all:

```
for some_dict in data["some_key"]:
    some_dict.update({"other_key": some_dict["other_key"].upper()})
```

And with that changed, even `dict.update()` is not necessary:

```
    some_dict["other_key"] = some_dict["other_key"].upper()
```