# How to append values to list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop

I want to append my list with values for each loop iteration:

```
        for i in range (4,10):
        a_list = [1,2,3]
        a_list = a_list.append(i)
```

The wanted output would be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]. But I get None. Also printing type(a_list) after using .append() gives me <class'NoneType'>. What is the problem here ?

Comment: `append` doesn't return a value, just write `a_list.append(i)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does append() always return None in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python)

Comment: Someone put a minus. Why make such hasty conclusions...?) Posted my own and the author's options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is mainly because of the fact that list.append method does not return anything, it appends the given value to the list in-place.

we can confirm this by the simple example below

```
a = list()
b = a.append(5)
>> print(b)
None
>> print(a)
[5]
```

As matter of fact,there is a simpler and more performant way to achieve this

```
>> a_list = [1,2,3]
>> a_list += list(range(4, 10))
>> print(a_list)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Here, we first shape a new list from a iterator **range(4, 10)**,
then we concate the two list together to get the list we want by adding the new list to the original list **a_list**.

by doing this, we can avoid the overhead caused by repeatedly call the **list.append** method in a for loop

Answer (score 1):

firstly, you have to mention a_list before for. instead, you will get [1, 2, 3, 9]. secondly, you give the a_list a value of a_list.append() function.

```
a_list = [1, 2, 3]
for i in range(4, 10):
    a_list.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a_list = []
for i in range (1,10):
    a_list.append(i)

print(a_list)
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

You have the wrong indentation on the loop.You need to add i at each iteration. Also, to get the list you want, you need to add 1, then 2, then 3, and so on. i this is what needs to be added. Put print(i) and print each iteration.

```
a_list = [1,2,3]
for i in range (4,10):
    a_list.append(i)

print(a_list)
```

If you use your option, it will be correct to declare an array once. And then only add values. See below.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```