# Appending int to end of list in python gives NONE

Tags: python-3.x, list

When I try `print([2,3].append(5))`, I get NONE as my output. Why is that? I expected to get [2,3,5].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does append() always return None in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python)

Comment: Its because `append()` is a function call , which does not return anything.