# why getting all possibilities of a list python don't work?

Tags: python, recursion

so I made a simple program which suppose to calculate all possible lists out of a given list.
for example [1,2,3]
the program suppose to return: [1,2,3], [2,3], [1,3], [1], [2], [3], []
but is 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append

```
def __bacteria(mass_list, count, option_list):
    if len(mass_list) == count:
        return option_list
    return __bacteria(mass_list,count+1, option_list.append(mass_list[count])) or __bacteria(mass_list,count+1, option_list)
```

Comment: "append" always returns "None" and modifies the list inplace. You can replace `option_list.append(mass_list[count])` with `option_list + [mass_list[count]]`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python

Comment: What value are you passing while calling function ?

Comment: Do you miss this - ```[1, 2]```?   Any lib is fine to use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, why doesn't it work? Let's add some type annotations and run a type checker like [MyPy](http://mypy-lang.org/), those help me personally figure out a lot of bugs:

```
def __bacteria(mass_list: list[int], count: int, option_list: list[int]) -> list[list[int]]:
    if len(mass_list) == count:
        return option_list  # error: list[int] given but list[list[int]] expected
    return __bacteria(mass_list, count + 1,
             option_list.append(mass_list[count]) # error: None given but list[int] expected
           ) or __bacteria(mass_list , count + 1, option_list)
```

Alright, so it shows 2 errors so far. What's the first one? Well, you return the current option, rather than a list of the current option.

As for the second one, [`list.append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) modifies the list in place, and returns `None`. Neither of those are what you want. What you want is, as suggested by @Michael Butscher: `option_list + [mass_list[count]]`. So now we have:

```
def __bacteria(mass_list: list[int], count: int, option_list: list[int]) -> list[list[int]]:
    if len(mass_list) == count:
        return [option_list]
    return (__bacteria(mass_list, count + 1, option_list + [mass_list[count]]) or
            __bacteria(mass_list, count + 1, option_list))
```

That should not give any errors when running a type checker or when running the code. But I bet it prints out the wrong thing. How could that happen?

The base case (`if len(mass_list) == count`) should be fine. The first recursive call seems fine too, and the second recursive call is fine as well. What's left? Only the `or`.

Now what does `or` do when given lists as arguments? Try it out on the interactive interpreter. What is the result of `[] or []`? And the result of `[1] or [2]`? And the result of `[] or [0]`? What is the logical rule that `or` implements when given two lists?

So what do we need here? Well, we know that `__bacteria` returns a list of lists (`list[list[int]]` to be precise) and we need to return a list of lists that contains the items of the list returned by the first recursive call and the items of the list returned by the second recursive call. That's what `+` does! So now we have:

```
def __bacteria(mass_list: list[int], count: int, option_list: list[int]) -> list[list[int]]:
    if len(mass_list) == count:
        return [option_list]
    return (__bacteria(mass_list, count + 1, option_list + [mass_list[count]]) +
            __bacteria(mass_list, count + 1, option_list))
```

We can do better than this. For one, we're building up a list by creating a lot of smaller lists and copying them to concatenate them multiple times. Try giving a larger `mass_list`, and see how your program slows down.

One way to make it faster and use less memory is by using a generator as a helper function. I'll rename the function and arguments to make things clearer:

```
from typing import Iterator

def powerset(items: list[int]) -> list[list[int]]:
    return list(powerset_helper(items, 0, []))

def powerset_helper(items: list[int], index: int, to_include: list[int]) -> Iterator[list[int]]:
    if index == len(items):
        yield to_include
        return
    yield from powerset_helper(items, index + 1, to_include + [items[index]])
    yield from powerset_helper(items, index + 1, to_include)
```

We can do even better than this, though, which is to simply use the answer by @Dalmas Otieno! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to get a power-set of a set. If so you can do it as follows:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def all_possible_lists(iterable):
    l = list(iterable)
    pset = chain.from_iterable(combinations(l, n) for n in range(len(l)+1))
    return [list(i) for i in pset]

print(all_possible_lists([1, 2, 3]))
```

and the output is

```
[[], [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: yes though I want to do it with out any external libs. I am currently thinking that mabey recursion is the right path. do you know if it is possible?

Comment: `itertools` comes with python. It is a class just like list, dict etc

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this *power set* w/o any lib?

Try this then:

```py
def powerSet(nums):
    ''' nums is a list, [1, 2, 3]
        generate all subset - by adding one at a time
    '''
    ans = [[]]
    for n in nums:
        ans += [a + [n] for a in ans]
    
    return ans

print(powerSet([1, 2, 3]))      # NB - if empty list is undesired, you could filter it out.
```

#### Output:

```
[[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```