# Can't get Python append to work - list returning empty

Tags: python, list, append

I'm calling/importing classes into a main script. Everything is working fine, except when I attempt to .append() a sys.argv[1] list into the function-list of the main calling class.
I've tried to move the list and functions to under both name == main and above the class definition. The sys/argv gets mapped back to a functions dictionary, and the functions are supposed to get appended to a list, however when printing the list both under name == main and inside the main script itself, the list is returned empty. Also when I print this:

print(function_list.append(out)) it returns None, so i don't think this is executing.

Notably this block of code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # functions_list = []
    from Connect_Handler import Connect
    inlist = sys.argv[1]
    outlist = inlist.split(",")
    print("This is outlist")
    print(outlist)
    print(type(outlist))
    for i in outlist:
        out = functions[i]
        print("This is out")
        print(out)
        print(function_list.append(out))
        function_list.append(out)
    Connector = Connect()
    print(time.perf_counter())
    Connector.connect_parser()
    print(time.perf_counter())
```

Printing outlist returns a list,
printing(type(outlists)) returns a class 'list',
printing out returns a function object,
printing the append function returns None.

so it doesn't seem to be appending anything.

here's the code block (the threading part may need a rework, I haven't tested it):

```
from Hardware_info import HardwareMaintenance
from OSPF import OSPFMaintenance as OSPF

OSPF = OSPF.OSPF_Handler
Hardware = HardwareMaintenance.hardware_handler
functions = {"Hardware": Hardware, "OSPF": OSPF}

thread_pool = Queue()
ip_pool = Queue()
function_list = []
thread_list = []
class Connect:

    def __init__(self,):
        intake_file = open('ip_list.txt', 'r')
        self.json_data = [json.loads(line) for line in intake_file]
        pass

    def connect_parser(self, inlist=[]):
        for data in self.json_data:
            ip = data["ip"]
            # port = data["port"]
            username = data["username"] if data["username"] else ""
            password = data["password"] if data["password"] else ""
            secret = data["secret"] if "secret" in data else False
            device_type = data["device_type"] if data["device_type"] else ""
            ip_pool.put(ip)

            if data["header"] == "Netmiko":
                print("The variables being passed:  " + ip, username, password, device_type)
                ConnectHandler = netmiko.ConnectHandler(
                    device_type=device_type,
                    host=ip,
                    username=username,
                    password=password,
                    port=22,
                    secret=data["secret"] if "secret" in data else False
                )
                if ConnectHandler:
                    try:
                        ConnectHandler.enable()
                    except Exception as e:
                        print("Could not connect to {}".format(ip))
                thread_pool.put(ConnectHandler)
        looper()

def looper():
    while not thread_pool.empty():
        conn = thread_pool.get(block=False)
        host = ip_pool.get(block=False)
        print("host      " + host)
        print(function_list)
        for i in function_list:
            print ("This is i inside Looper")
            print(i)
            res = threading.Thread(target=i, args = (conn, host),  daemon=True)
            res.start()
            print(res.__repr__())
            thread_list.append(res)
    for i in thread_list:
        i.join()
        print("This is the threads list")
        print(i.__repr__())



if __name__ == "__main__":
    # functions_list = []
    from Connect_Handler import Connect
    inlist = sys.argv[1]
    outlist = inlist.split(",")
    print("This is outlist")
    print(outlist)
    print(type(outlist))
    for i in outlist:
        out = functions[i]
        print("This is out")
        print(out)
        print(function_list.append(out))
        function_list.append(out)
    Connector = Connect()
    print(time.perf_counter())
    Connector.connect_parser()
    print(time.perf_counter())
```

also under the looper() function above:

print("host      " + host),
print(function_list)

host x.x.x.x is returned, but an empty list is also returned.

I manually added multiple functions to the list above the class definition, and it works, and ran the code in about 23 seconds, and so i'm assuming even the threading is probably working(which I will test more later, I even realize I'm running my ConnectHandler sequentially).

```
thread_pool = Queue()
ip_pool = Queue()
function_list = [Hardware, OSPF]
thread_list = []
```

as above the function_list = [Hardware, OSPF], and now the entire code runs.

But I want to append to this list from my CLI list, the split on my sys.argv[1] is working, but the appending is not...

Any ideas to improve my code?

I've spent about 3 hours on trying to append properly and it is not working :(

Also note I am running "Connect_Handler.py [Hardware,OSPF]" from the CLI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does append() always return None in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python)

Comment: I actually just read that, as part of suggestions.   I tried importing functions_list under name==main, and it seems to be doing something but very slowly, and still not working correctly...

Answer (score 0):

So I got it to work by importing `functions_list` under `__main__`.
I remember taking classes in Python for bad list references, but didn't realize I was imporoperly referencing the list declared in the calling program/main script in this situation (In fact I wasn't referencing at all).

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # functions_list = []
    from __main__ import function_list
    from __main__ import Connect
    Connector = Connect()
    inlist = sys.argv[1]
    outlist = inlist.split(",")
    print("This is outlist")
    print(outlist)
    print(type(outlist))
    for i in outlist:
        out = functions[i]
        print("This is out")
        print(out)
        function_list.append(out)
    print(function_list)
    print(time.perf_counter())
    Connector.connect_parser()
    print(time.perf_counter())
```

The code executed in 19 seconds with calling 2 outside classes, however I need to tinker with my threads a bit as I used a workaround, because as of now I am sequentially calling my `ConnectHandler`, and popping items from Queues....